# How do I Post jsonObject into api use MVVM in Android?

Tags: android, json, mvvm, retrofit2, viewmodel

I know Retrofit can get api data , but I need to redesign project use MVVM , many tutorials in kotlin, but I am used to java , I need some  tutorials in java , any suggestions ?

for example , I get api code like this :

POST into api command :

```
  { "apiName":"getDevicePairInfo","DeviceIDKey":"androidkey","Code":"TW" }
```

I create a interface call ApiProxy ,

```
  public interface ApiProxy {
     String BASE_URL ="https:10.23.57:120/DEMO/api/";
     @GET("GetDevicePairInfo")
     Call<List<DeviceInfo>> getDevice(); //it's empty?
```

How to using Android ViewModel to load data Asynchronously using Retrofit ?

give me website or any documents both ok, Thanks.

Comment: I've created MVVM demo with Retrofit and Rxjava but unfortunately it's in kotlin. Although you can take reference to it and can implement your functionality.
https://github.com/pt147/MVVM-Demo

Comment: @Parth:Thanks , but I still used to Java , not kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewModel

```
private void loadData() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<List<DeviceInfo>> call = api.getDeviceInfo();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DeviceInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<DeviceInfo>> call, Response<List<DeviceInfo>> response) {

                //setting the list to MutableLiveData
                mDeviceInfoList.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<DeviceInfo>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , but I still stuck in ApiProxy , My json request is  { "apiName":"getDevicePairInfo","DeviceIDKey":"androidkey","Code":"TW" } , Call<List<DeviceInfo>> getDevice(); //respones is null